# Youtube playlist ID

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, playlist

I've created a playlist on youtube. The url works great but I can't get the ID out of it. It doesn't seem to work.

My playlist is :

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE_-2rZv8j2ro-QgxzK9nvi9O61dgE-Hx

And when I plug " E_-2rZv8j2ro-QgxzK9nvi9O61dgE-Hx " into the youtube player demo, it doesn't work : https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

I need that ID to make an API Iframe.

Thank's for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The player demo has a bug wrt new ids.
Try [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

`<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=playlist&list=PLE_-2rZv8j2ro-QgxzK9nvi9O61dgE-Hx"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>`